# Derivative of a map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

> Let $$f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$$$$(x,y,z) \rightarrow (x+2y,yz)$$
>   $\bullet$ Compute the derivative of $f$
>   $\bullet$ Using the derivative of $f$ find the derivative $Dg$ where $$g: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ is defined by $g(x)=||f(x)||^2=f(x).f(x)$.

**MY ATTEMPT**
So firstly I computed the derivative of $f$ i.e $Df$ as ;
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & z & y  \end{array} \right)$$
But I am having trouble with the second part.. I have not found derivatives of $\mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ maps before.
Does the definition of $g(x)=f(x).f(x)$ imply multiplying the matrices.. but you can't due to wrong dimensions
Any help or hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is an inner product: $(a,b)\cdot (c,d)=ac+bd$.

Comment: @Tomás  So would this be correct ? $Dg=f(x)^{T}Df+(Df)^{T}f(x)$ ??

Comment: @Tomás or like you said with inner product wouldn't it rather be $D(ff)(x)=f(x)Df(x)+f(x)Df(x)$ using the product rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lemma :

Let F: $\mathbb{R}^{n\times q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m\times p}$ be given by
$$F(A) = G(A)H(A),$$ 
where $G:\mathbb{R}^{n\times q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m\times r}$ and  $H:\mathbb{R}^{n\times q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{r\times p}$. Then the following relation hold 
$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial A} = (H^T\otimes I_M) \frac{\partial G}{\partial A} + (I_p\otimes G) \frac{\partial H}{\partial A} $$ 
where H^T denotes the transpose of H.

In you case, it will be 
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial a} =  \frac{\partial \, f^Tf}{\partial a} = 2 \ f^T\frac{\partial \, f}{\partial a} $$

with $a = [x,y,z]^T$ and $f = [x+2y,yz]^T$.